# Solaris 10 zone: ping does not resolve but nslookup does

Tags: domain-name-system, ping, solaris-10, zones

This question is very specific to Solaris 10 zones.
I have a master zone and another zone.
The master zone is working correctly with respect to DNS lookups: 'ping google.ca' works as does 'nslookup google.ca'.
The file /etc/resolv.conf exists, has the correct DNS servers, and the default router is correct. ALL IS WORKING.

On the zone, 'ping google.ca' says "unknown host google.ca". However, 'nslookup google.ca' give the correct IP.

The zone has been setup correctly as far as I know - the default router is correct, netstat -nr shows what I expect to see including only one defaultrouter.

Zones don't normally have a /etc/resolv.conf file, but just to test I created one that's the same as in the root zone (and is correct). No change.

How do I set up the zone so that ping will work? (the inability to resolve domain names is causing other problems that I really need to fix).

The master zone has 'resolv.conf' and so I can ping named servers i.e. 'ping mydomain.com' from the server.

The second zone does not have resolv.conf, and I cannot ping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reviewed some old system build notes, and found (and tested) the solution.

I did create the proper `/etc/resolv.conf` in the zone, but that wasn't enough. You also need to edit the default `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

the entry

```
hosts: files
```

needs to be changed to

```
hosts: files dns
```

saved, and then reboot the zone. Ping "domain name" now works.